# Pandas search for all instances and replace all instances found

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        ['Mind Map', 'MM', '...'], 
        ['Other Term', '', 'Some other term with some words like communication and references to glossary and MM.'], 
        ['Another Term', '', 'Another term with a reference to other term and glossary.'],
        ['Glossary', '', '...']
        ]),columns=['Term', 'Abbreviation', 'Description'])
```

As you can see in the description of `other term` and `another term`, the description has references to either a term or a abbreviation somewhere else defined in the data frame.

Now my goal is that when the description has a reference to a term or abbreviation (case in-sensitive) which is found in the data frame. The term or abbreviation within the description is replaced with a link to the term by embedding some html in it; `<a href="search.com/?q=$Term">\1</a>`

So in this case in `Other term` description, `glossary` and `MM` need to be replaced. In case of `Another term` description, `other term` and `glossary` need to be replaced.

**Is it possible to do this with Python Pandas?**

What do I currently have?

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
term = 'Glossary'
df['Description'].apply(
    lambda x: re.sub(r'\b(' + term + r')\b',
                     '<a href="search.com/?q=' + term + r'">\1</a>', 
                     x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

But this only replaces one fixed term/abbreviation, in this case 'glossary'. I am unsure how to extend this (without a for-loop) to all terms and abbreviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
# defining all terms you want to replace
terms = ["Glossary", "words"]
terms_r = [term + "(?i)" for term in terms]
# replace pattern
replacement = ['<a href="search.com/?q=' + term + r'">\\1</a>' for term in terms]
# create a dict with term:replacement
pattern = dict(zip(terms_r, replacement))

# replace it according to pattern dict
df["Description"].replace(pattern, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0                                                                                                                                                    ...
1    Some other term with some <a href="search.com/?q=words">\1</a> like communication and references to <a href="search.com/?q=Glossary">\1</a> and MM.
2                                                               Another term with a reference to other term and <a href="search.com/?q=Glossary">\1</a>.
3                                                                                                                                                    ...
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

Comment: I understand your suggestion, but I cannot set replace to be case insensitive? That is where I am stuck with your suggestion. Furthermore, your suggestion does not incorporate for the regex backreference `\1` and word boundaries. What I have changed/added with your suggestion; `regex = [r'\b(' + term + r')\b' for term in terms]` and `replacement = ['<a href="search.com/?q=' + term + r'">\1</a>' for term in terms]`, `pattern = dict(zip(regex, replacement))`, but then I am stuck with the case sensitivity.

Comment: I've updated my solution, but I hat to tweak it around a bit. Could you try again? Left the regex out yet to test the case insensitivity.

Comment: fixed an error in the code... sorry. `pattern = dict(zip(terms_r, replacement))` instead of `pattern = dict(zip(terms, replacement))`